# Read backslashes from propertyfile

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I have a property file: project.properties in which I store some property, such as `JAVA_PATH=D:\Application\Java8`.

I am trying to read it by Java using *FileInputStream*.

```
InputStream input = null;
input = new FileInputStream("D:\\Application\\project.properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(input);

String javaPath = props.getProperty("JAVA_PATH");
System.out.println("JAVA_PATH : "+javaPath);
```

The output I am getting is:

```
JAVA_PATH : D:ApplicationJava8
```

I understand that Java treats this as an escape character and removes it. But is there any way I can read the property as it is by any kind of massaging?

I want the output as `JAVA_PATH : D:\Application\Java8`.

Comment: Add `\\\` instead of `\\` in your property file

Answer (score 0):

The `\` needs to be escaped with an additional `\` in the *.properties* file, like so:

```
JAVA_PATH=D:\\Application\\Java8
```